# How to observe recyclerview actionmode click in activity

Tags: android, mvvm, android-recyclerview, delegates

(Rookie Android dev here)

I implemented the actionmode callback within my recyclerview (might be a bad choice as well, please advise if it is, in detail, with a good tutorial/example), so that when the user clicks on the listitem, it gets selected easily.

What I want to do is observe actionmode button push, and display a list of floating action buttons (or menu). I want them to get animated on show and on hide, and trigger various stuff (**on the recyclerview items**) when pushed.

I sort of know how to do this in a very dirty way: pass on `List<FloatingActionButton>` and animations to the view from the activity. But I would like to know the best practice of how to accomplish this. Also, an observable view (which is observed by the viewmodel or activity) kinda feels a silly option to me, and I have no experience with delegates.

My actioncallback looks like this:

```
private ActionMode.Callback actionModeCallbacks = new ActionMode.Callback() {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {

        mode.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_contextual_items, menu);

        isActionModePresent = true;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.cab_action_select_all:
                selectedAppsHashSet.addAll(itemList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.cab_action_select_none:
                selectedAppsHashSet.clear();
                notifyDataSetChanged();
                return true;

            case R.id.cab_action_selecty_apply_green:
                //implement stuff here
                return true;

            case R.id.cab_action_selecty_apply_red:
                //implement stuff here
                return true;

            default:
                return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        isActionModePresent = false;
        selectedAppsHashSet.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
};
```

Comment: You can create an Interface to listen clicks on items of RecyclerView. You can view similar implementation in this tutorial https://www.androidhive.info/2017/02/android-creating-gmail-like-inbox-using-recyclerview/

Comment: This indeed solved my problem. I would accept this answer if it was a resoinse rather than a comment.